# draw multiple circles with imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to draw multiple circles on a background image, but im having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

Ive tried passing multiple imageMagick instances to the draw function but did not work.

So then I tried creating a new image object, and setting it to transparent.
Then i tried the drawing an image on top of that, but i cant get it to adjust the opacity at all.

Along the lines of what i am trying to do is this:
[image]

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    function drawImage(Imagick $im) {
    //    $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
          $im->setImageFormat("jpg");
          header("Content-Type: image/" . $im->getImageFormat());
          echo $im;
          exit;
    }

    // define circle mask
    $layer = new Imagick('spc.jpg');

    //now we need the height and width.
    $width = $layer->getImageWidth();
    $height = $layer->getImageHeight();
    $x = $width/2;
    $y = $height/2;

    $endX = $x + 150;
    $endY = $y + 150;

    $circle = new ImagickDraw();
    $circle->setFillColor("#FFFF00");
    $circle->circle($x, $y, $endX, $endY);
    //$layer->drawImage($circle, $circle2);

     $circle2 = new ImagickDraw();
     $circle2->setFillColor("#0000FF");
     $circle2->circle(0, 0, $x, $y);
     $layer->drawImage($circle, $circle2);

   drawImage($layer);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

drawImage shoud get only 1 parameter. try this at the final lines:

```
$layer->drawImage($circle);
$layer->drawImage($circle2);
drawImage($layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think/hope this is nearer to what you are aiming for... I have hacked around a bit because my environment is different from yours - but you should be able to see what I have done.

The main difference is that you need to set the fill colour to `transparent` and the stroke colour to whatever colour you want the circle outlines to be drawn in. Also, I have reused your Draw object rather than creating additional ones for each circle.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    function drawImage(Imagick $im) {
          $im->setImageFormat("jpg");
          $im->writeImage('out.jpg');
          exit;
    }

    // define circle mask
    $layer = new Imagick();
    $layer->newImage(500,250,new ImagickPixel('white'));
    $layer->borderImage('#6000ff',3,3);

    //now we need the height and width.
    $width = $layer->getImageWidth();
    $height = $layer->getImageHeight();
    $x = $width/2;
    $y = $height/2;

    $circle = new ImagickDraw();
    $circle->setFillColor('transparent'); // transparent
    $circle->setStrokeColor("#0000FF");   // blue
    $circle->circle($x, $y, $x + 25, $y);
    $layer->drawImage($circle);

    $circle->setStrokeColor("#00FF00");   // green
    $circle->circle($x, $y, $x + 50, $y);
    $layer->drawImage($circle);

    $circle->setStrokeColor("#FF00FF");   // purple
    $circle->circle($x, $y, $x +75, $y);
    $layer->drawImage($circle);

    $circle->setStrokeColor("#FF0000");   // red
    $circle->circle($x, $y, $x +100, $y);
    $layer->drawImage($circle);

    drawImage($layer);
?>
```

[image]